# How can I apply the exact same filter to multiple photos like this account?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, filter, contrast

[image]

I have multiple photos and I want to be consistent in their appearance like the attached photo. I am new and haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Answer (score 2):

[Creating a Photoshop action](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html) and running it on a folder with Photoshop's [Batch Processor](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html) is the most straightforward answer. However, this doesn't seem complicated enough to warrant that much effort. This seems more like a simple transparency effect. Putting an image on the bottom layer, with the next layer as a solid color with some blending mode and transparency applied to it, and finally some text as the top layer. In this set-up, you would just need to swap out the photo and text layers for each item. This may take less time than the action for a small volume of photos. If you wanted to get really weird with it, you might be able to do this with a [datamerge](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-data-driven-graphics.html).

In either case, you'd need to make sure the images all have similar brightness and contrast before applying any transparency effects, otherwise the results won't appear consistent even though the exact same effect is getting applied to each image.